# Measure size of individual responses in Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0, codahale-metrics

We use Jersey 2.x (Jersey + Spring + tomcat) to expose REST based web services. For monitoring purpose, I need to maintain a histogram capturing the size of responses sent out by the server to clients over time. Is it possible to do it using Jersey?

One [suggested way](https://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/dump-request-and-response-using-javaxservletfilter/) is to write a Servlet Filter (for tomcat) which will read every (request &) response and capture size information for responses. But, I am worried about the performance impact due to introduction of filter. Hence, I am looking for any solution using Jersey.

Any other suggestion (way out) will also be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if you could use an Interceptor with hk2?  See https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b34/extensibility.html#Interception

Comment: Well, I am not in a position to add another framework to fulfil the need.